# Find vector equation of a line given by a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

1) Write the vector equation of the line in $\mathbb R^3$ given by:

\begin{align}
x+y+z&=6 \\
x+2y+z&=1
\end{align}

2) Write the vector equation of the plane in $\mathbb R^3$ that passing through (1,0,-1) and is perpendicular to the line of exercise 1)

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the first equation from the second gives $y=-5$.  In this plane, you want all the points satisfying $x+z=11$, which is a line.

Parametrically, we can give it as $(t,-5,11-t)$, for all real $t$.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, a plane is defined by a point and a normal direction (a direction that is perpendicular to every vector in your plane). In this exercise, this direction is the direction vector of your line which was given by vadim123: $\vec{d}=(1,0,-1)$.
Using that and the given point, the equation of the plane is
$$((x,y,z) - (1,0,-1))\bullet (1,0,-1)=0$$
Also, you can write your equation as $$x-z =2$$